# How to create only one worker thread in Apache module?

Tags: module, apache2

I develop an Apache module that will run under MS Windows only.

I want it to spawn exectly one addidtion thread that will do some permament system monitoring task and store results in global variables. These variables will be read by subsequent HTTP GET requests.

I start a thread in

```
static void ite_mymodule_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)
```

using

```
if(hThread == 0) {
        print(L"creating thread\n");
        hThread= CreateThread(0, 0, thread, 0, 0, 0);
        if(hThread != 0) {
            print(L"thread created\n");
        } else {
            printLastError();
        }
    }
```

where hThread is a module's global variable, 
but instead of one additional thread I get two ?
How to prevent it ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

Under Widnws apache starts 2 processes:

- a master process and
- a worker process.

Each module's dll is  loaded into both master and worker processes, so we have two independent sets of module global variables.

For each module "`static void ite_mymodule_register_hooks(apr_pool_t *p)`" is called twice.

But there is a function passed to `ap_hook_child_init(...)` that i called `ite_child_init` that gets called only once and only for child process, so the thread should be started in this funcion.